# Should I consider debouncing my push button?

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit, breadboard, button, debounce

Considering a +5V battery source, I have a set of input switches. These switches are push buttons which stay closed upon clicking and open upon clicking again.

One side of a switch is connected to the positive side of the battery while the other is connected to a pull-down resistor, 10 kΩ specifically, and my combinational circuit.
This circuit contains 74LS-series DIP ICs.

[image: circuit]

With that set-up should I still consider debouncing my circuit or not?

I'm thinking whether this set-up can affect one of my sequential circuit which send pulses when one input is clicked with the use of XOR gates, capacitors and resistors.

Comment: obviously, that depends on your circuit! So, without you sharing that, it'll be hard to answer. Anyway, it's likely that debouncing is a good idea – but you've probably know that already, else you wouldn't ask here, would you? :)

Comment: Here's a sample of my circuit... https://www.dropbox.com/s/48nxpl10crki66p/Drawing1.png?dl=0

Comment: The output releases a pulse whenever one input is clicked. Without debouncing, will this have erroneous results?

Comment: You copied that circuit from somewhere and didn't quite understand it, right? I'd like to push you in the right direction: what purpose does the third gate, and the resistor and capacitor serve?

Comment: It detects the positive and negative edges from the pulses of the preceding XOR gates.

Comment: exactly. And what does "bouncing" mean in context of switches?

Comment: It's when the push button oscillates from high to low in short instances as you turn the switch close or open.

Comment: If the bounce causes unacceptable behavior, yes; if not, no.

Comment: @OrlandoLewis - FYI that circuit as currently shown **will not work reliably** (or perhaps not at all). The 10kΩ pull-down resistor value is too high to guarantee that the input voltage to each LS TTL input will be below 0.8V (V(IL)), when the switches are open, so they may not be seen as "low". Note I(IL) for LS TTL is up to 0.4 mA. See detailed explanation on this previous question "[Pull down resistor on logic gate input](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/238224)". And similar (for "standard" TTL so I(IL) = up to 1.6mA) [on this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/136572).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should consider debouncing your push button if the push button does not do this for you.

Comment: Upvoting obvious answer because it's obvious. Not a great answer – but still answers OP's question "should I consider…".

Comment: Upvoting Marcus comment. Obvious comment is obvious. So meta! :-)

Comment: Upvoting @winny .... just because.

Comment: Upvoting winny because recursiveness is recursive.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you have a circuit that detects edges and triggers some action (counter, interrupt, etc) then you need to debounce, otherwise every edge of a bouncing switch will be counted.

Some applications simply poll logic level periodically looking for a high or low state. In those cases you might be able to get away without debouncing, but you need to study the specifics of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should debounce the switches if bouncing on opening or closing would cause trouble.  This really should have been obvious.

We don't know what's in the "output" block in your diagram, so we can't say.  It looks like you have a edge to glitch converter in front of it.  Bouncing switches would therefore cause multiple glitches.  Again, only you can say whether that's OK or not.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, it would be useful to explain what exactly you think is incorrect, misleading, or badly written. I still believe this answer is correct.